# Initialize array with random numbers and bubble sort

Tags: vb.net

This is the code that only generates 1 number with button 2 click.  I need it to take the 10 numbers from button 1 click in the array and produce the same ten numbers sorted from least to greatest:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim numberArray(9) As Integer
    Dim generator As New Random


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim min As Integer
        Dim r As Integer
        Dim max As Integer
        min = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        max = Val(TextBox2.Text)
        Label1.Text = ""
        For r = 0 To numberArray.GetUpperBound(0)
            numberArray(r) = generator.Next(min, max)
            Label1.Text += numberArray(r) & " "
            Label1.Text += ControlChars.NewLine
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


        Dim r As Integer
        Dim intTemp As Integer
        Dim blnExhchangeMade As Boolean
        blnExhchangeMade = False
        Do While blnExhchangeMade


            For r = LBound(numberArray) To (UBound(numberArray) - 1)
                If numberArray(r) < numberArray(r + 1) Then
                    intTemp = numberArray(r)
                    numberArray(r) = numberArray(r + 1)
                    numberArray(r + 1) = intTemp
                    blnExhchangeMade = True

                End If

            Next
        Loop
        Label2.Text += numberArray(r) & " "
        Label2.Text += ControlChars.NewLine
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is the array just not sorted?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort  Translate the Pseudocode

Comment: You haven't written this yourself. You can tell because you've used `GetUpperBound` in one place and `UBound` in another. You should really try to understand the algorithm and write the code yourself. I think you'll find that you can solve this yourself. The pseudo-code that Plutonix linked to is a good start.

Comment: I'll give you a clue though - (1) `blnExhchangeMade = False` (2) `Do While blnExhchangeMade`.

Comment: As a side note, you're only generating numbers between `min` & `max - 1`. The second parameter on `Random.Next` is an _exclusive_ upper bound.

Comment: I deleted the private sub for button 2.  I get a list of random numbers that are in no particular order but, when I go to sort them I get nothing.  I would like to display the unsorted numbers in label 1 and the sorted numbers in label 2.

Comment: I am getting a {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."} warning

Comment: Yes, you would be getting that. Just follow the logic of the code and you'll find out where that it happening.

Comment: @CertIntrovert23 - don't forget to `@` me when you comment back to me as I didn't get a notification of your comments before. `@username` is the format.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I made a change and now I get nothing and no errors.  This is what I have now for button 2...

Comment: @Enigmativity Do While blnExhchangeMade

            blnExhchangeMade = False
            For lngY = LBound(numberArray) To (UBound(numberArray) - 1)
                If numberArray(r) > numberArray(r + 1) Then
                    intTemp = numberArray(r)
                    numberArray(r) = numberArray(r + 1)
                    numberArray(r + 1) = intTemp
                    blnExhchangeMade = True
                End If

            Next
            Label2.Text += numberArray(r) & " "

        Loop

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah, that looks like crap.  I understand the logic of bubble sort.  Just not translating it into code.  Maybe if I did 81 If then statments I could do it but, I know there has to be a simpler way.

Comment: @CertIntrovert23 - Here's something to look at: why are you looping with `lngY` and indexing by `r`? My suggestion would be to make `r` local in both methods.

Comment: @Enigmativity Now I'm only getting one number at a time.  I need to list out the same ten numbers in rank from least to greatest.  I am not getting any errors though.  That's a plus.

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited the post to show the code I have now.  I have no idea how to get this to produce the ten numbers in numerical order.

Comment: Nevermind all...assignment was due at midnight eastern time.  I had to turn it what I had.  Maybe I'll figure it out one day!

Comment: @CertIntrovert23 - You truly weren't far off in your code, but you really didn't take time to think through the code to see what was happening. I could tell because you took out the second `blnExhchangeMade = False` without even thinking that the first `blnExhchangeMade = False` was the problem. It should have been `blnExhchangeMade = True`. After that you probably would have knocked off the rest of the issues easily. Nevertheless I've posted my version of the code for you to look at.

Comment: Don't do `Label1.Text += ...`, it can cause problems. Use the ampersand there too: `Label1.Text &= ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I would have gone with:

```
Private Const elements As Integer = 9
Private numberArray(elements - 1) As Integer
Private generator As New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim min As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim max As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    Label1.Text = ""
    For r = 0 To elements - 1
        numberArray(r) = generator.Next(min, max + 1)
        Label1.Text += numberArray(r) & " "
        Label1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim intTemp As Integer
    Dim blnExhchangeMade As Boolean = True
    Do While blnExhchangeMade
        blnExhchangeMade = False
        For r = 0 To elements - 2
            If numberArray(r) > numberArray(r + 1) Then
                intTemp = numberArray(r)
                numberArray(r) = numberArray(r + 1)
                numberArray(r + 1) = intTemp
                blnExhchangeMade = True
            End If
        Next
    Loop
    Label1.Text = ""
    For r = 0 To elements - 1
        Label1.Text += numberArray(r) & " "
        Label1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  I knew something had to be wrong with using min and max from the first button.  I plan on fixing mine and using it later to develop another Windows program for my own use.  I was pulling hairs out last night trying to figure it out.  I deleted and started over numerous times.  I had to take CB as a requirement but, after this semester I will be focusing on c# and Python.  Are there any books or references that you think might better help me understand loops?

Comment: @CertIntrovert23 - Loops are a fairly fundamental part of imperative programming (VB.NET, C#, Python are all in that class). I don't think you have a problem with loops. I think it is more your ability to run the program in your head to debug it properly. That just comes with practice. I would be more inclined to write small test programs that slightly push your understanding so that your learn by small steps.